Bathroom cabinet receding
I wanted to recede my bathroom cabinet. When I took out part of the dry wall, I found this:



My question is, can I cut one of these 2 x 4 to make room for the cabinet?

Most of it looking like packing/filler to fit the cabinet/not structural.

which one you want to cut

@Traveler The front one. There are two 2 x 4 side by side joined by that OSB board that can be seen there. The cabinet is only 3 5/8 deep, so just cutting the front 2 x 4 will be okay.

the horizontal top one ?

@Traveler That one and then the 2 vertical ones. I may be wrong but I think this structure was made not for support but to allow room for the shower plumbing. The wall was normal thickness up to this point, then they added a second 2 x 4 to double the wall so they were able to fit the bathtub-shower plumbing later.

Can you give us a photo with more context?

@Huesmann I posted 3 more pictures.

How far do you need to countersink your cabinet?

@Huesmann some 3 and a half inches

@agcala and how deep are your studs?  You have quite the mishmash of framing there!  Do you have any idea if this is a structural wall?  My guess is no, but I have limited info here.
